# Could anyone help me with the script for this

Tags: mysql, sql-server

have a table like this

```
    empid    questionid   options
    1        1            A
    2        1            A
    3        1            B
    4        1            C
```

now i need result like this

```
    questionid   responseA   responseB   responseC
    1            50%         25%         25%
```

Comment: Can you format it a bit better?

Comment: according to example you should want B and C to have 25% right ?

Comment: yeah Gaby. you are right

Comment: Why is this tagged `server`? If it's `sql-server`, then why the `mysql` tag? Do you have other responses (except for `A`, `B`, `C`)`?

Comment: sorry i am a new user. I gave a blank space in between sql and server. it is edited and saved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could PIVOT;

```
SELECT questionid, (A / total) * 100 responseA, (B / total) * 100 responseB, (C / total) * 100 responseC FROM (
    SELECT T1.questionid, T1.options, T2.total
    FROM the_tbl T1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT questionid, CAST(COUNT(*) AS MONEY) AS total FROM the_tbl GROUP BY questionID) T2 ON T2.questionid = T1.questionid
) T
PIVOT (
    COUNT(options) FOR options IN ([A], [B], [C])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY questionid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(100/
  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM your_Table as t2
    WHERE t2.questionid = t1.questionid )
  * COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR) + '%' AS 'Percent', OPTIONS, questionid
FROM your_Table as t1
--WHERE questionid = 2
GROUP BY OPTIONS, questionid
ORDER BY questionid;
```

This is one possible way you could do it
(works on SQL-Server but not sure if it does in MySql)

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
  questionid,
  SUM(CASE options WHEN 'A' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(options)   AS responseA,
  SUM(CASE options WHEN 'B' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(options)   AS responseB,
  SUM(CASE options WHEN 'C' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(options)   AS responseC
FROM 
  answers
GROUP BY
  questionid
```

Note: To avoid casting and multiplying 100, I used `100.0` and `0.0` values in `CASE ... END` expressions.

Comment: Of course, it is applicable if options are A, B or C. To add '%' to the end of statistic values you should cast the statements to `varchar`: `CAST( SUM(...) / COUNT(...) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '%'`.